# Importing values from excel to access with criteria from access table

Tags: vba, ms-access

First of all, thanks in advance for your time and help. Here is my situation;

I'm trying to add some values from an existing excel workbook into an existing table in an access database. Here is the code I've found and played with it a little according to my needs, but when I click on the button, it does nothing. No error messages, no imported values, just does nothing.

```
Private Sub Command39_Click()

On Error GoTo Err_Handler

Dim wbFDU As Workbook
Dim objExcelApp As Excel.Application
Dim db As Database
Dim rstWL As Recordset
Dim columnI As String
Dim columnS As String
Dim searchInC As String
Dim C As String
Dim I As String
Dim M As String
Dim S As String
Dim W As String

Dim iCounter As Integer

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rstWL = db.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM WL WHERE WLDate = Date()-1")

Set objExcelApp = New Excel.Application
objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open ("\\CDB\Shared\MNG\CIO Mng.xlsm")
Set wbFDU = objExcelApp.Workbooks(1)

If rstWL.EOF = False Then

    rstWL.MoveFirst
    Do While rstWL.EOF = False

        iCounter = 1
        C = "C" & iCounter
        I = "I" & iCounter
        M = "M" & iCounter
        S = "S" & iCounter
        W = "W" & iCounter

        Do Until wbFDU.Worksheets("Rep").Range(C).Value = ""

            searchInC = wbFDU.Worksheets("Rep").Range(C).Value

            If rstWL!CustName = searchInC Then

               columnI = wbFDU.Worksheets("Rep").Range(I).Value + wbFDU.Worksheets("Rep").Range(M).Value
               columnS = wbFDU.Worksheets("Rep").Range(S).Value + wbFDU.Worksheets("Rep").Range(W).Value

                rstWL.Edit
                rstWL.Fields("LCDCO") = columnI
                rstWL.Update
                rstWL.Fields("ECDCO") = columnS
                rstWL.Update

            End If

            iCounter = iCounter + 1
            C = "C" & iCounter
            I = "I" & iCounter
            M = "M" & iCounter
            S = "S" & iCounter
            W = "W" & iCounter
        Loop

        rstWL.MoveNext
    Loop

End If

wbFDU.Close False
Set wbFDU = Nothing

rstWL.Close
Set rstWL = Nothing
db.Close
Set db = Nothing
Exit Sub

Err_Handler:

MsgBox "The following error has occured." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
    "Error Number " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
    "Error Description" & Err.Description & vbCrLf & _
    "Your application will close!", _
    vbCritical, "An Error has Occured"

End Sub
```

Since couple of days cannot figure it out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you intending to update or append records since you claim *no imported values*? If the latter use [Recordset.AddNew](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845624.aspx) and call entire table instead of specific `SELECT`. Also try first `If`block as:`If rstWL.RecordCount > 0`.

Comment: My intention is to update the records. Access table has the customer id with other values (and same customer id might be exist on many different dates, that's the reason I'm trying to call the recordset with Date()-1 criteria so only the date I have in excel file will be effected) . Excel sheet has some of the customers with a different value and that's the value I need to bring into the fields in access table as an update.

Comment: Try pressing F8 to step through the code one line at a time.  It's possible the lines `Do Until wbFDU.Worksheets("Rep").Range(C).Value = ""` and `If rstWL!CustName = searchInC Then` prevent your update from firing.

Comment: If nothing happens, then either your query returns no results, or nothing is updated.

Comment: Thank you very very much Parfait and destination-data, for your time and valuable input! Code is working fine now, problem was the source Excel file, Range C was having empty cells after 4 rows, so the code was stopping there. I've found another problem though; there are some customers with 2 or more actions in same day, so the code brings the same total amount for each and every record that particular customer having action. I'm trying to get rid of those duplicates now. Tricky part is, all the actions must remain in access table, but the data from Excel file must come only once.

Answer (score 0):

Consider directly querying Excel workbook in MS Access without the need of recordset looping. Specifically, use a temp table re-created or cleaned out each time to use in `UPDATE` query with *WL*.

However, it seems your workbook does not use any column headers, so specify `HDR=No` which will result in F1, F2, F3, ... in query resultset. Otherwise, use `HDR=Yes` and reference named columns.

**Make-Table** Query *(after first time, use delete/append query for subsequent Excel updates)*

```sql
SELECT *
INTO myExcelTempTable
FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No;Database=\\CDB\Shared\MNG\CIO Mng.xlsm].[Rep$] AS t;
```

**Update** Query

```sql
UPDATE WL 
INNER JOIN myExcelTempTable AS t
ON WL.CustomerId = t.F3           --F3  being Column C (customer id)

SET LCDCO = F9,                   --F9  being Column I
    ECDCO = F19                   --F19 being Column S

WHERE WL.WLDate = Date()-1;
```

*Do not use comments in above query in MS Access. Only included here to guide you.*

Comment: Thanks a lot again Parfait, I will try this approach as soon as I can. Never worked with this kind of queries before and would love to learn them.